# Getting the order object from observer issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, event-observer

Is there a way to get the order object from this event

```
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder
```

Apparently it doesn't know about the order by using this:
`$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()` .I know I could use the save order after or before event, but I would like to use that event . Is there a way to get the order object from that event ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get order object on `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveorder` event by like this,

```
$order = Mage::registry('hss_order');
```

You can find the usage of this event in below location,

`app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\etc\config.xml`

and

`app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Observer.php` in `setResponseAfterSaveOrder` method

Comment: but what happens If i disable the paypal module? , i'm not sure if this will still work :)  thnx

Comment: Disable the PayPal module means? You did not mention that in your question :) @Chester

Comment: I know, but i would like to avoid this kind of dependencies. What happens if tomorrow it will be decide to not use anymore paypal payment method ? will this still work ? thnx

Comment: No, it will not work, but you can also do the same thing like magento. register the registry in `checkout_submit_all_after` and get the order object `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveorder ` event. If you don't want to set the dependency on `PayPal`